# Where can I find information and how can I monitor that Snowflake complies with the SLA agreement?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Where can I find information and how can I monitor that Snowflake complies with the SLA agreement?

How to monitor, for example, such parameters under the SLA agreement with Snowflake:

- Performance reports from service provider
- Key Performance Indicators
- Service Delivery Reports
- Self-certification
- Independent Reviews
- Reports on Business Continuity Measures
- Testing reports

On what basis can I settle Snowflake for failure to meet the SLA agreement?

Does Snowflake provide any information?

Which of the above-mentioned points am I able to get online?

Comment: There is a team that maintains some of those documents. Your sales team can request that they send the ones that are available.

Comment: I have to monitor these parameters at least once a month, it can be a hassle asking the sales team to do this every time. But this is a starting point.

Comment: That team does not maintain the information that is changing frequently, but for the ones on your list they do have they'll be able to provide reports.